# Radial delta function - rigorous justification

Tags: reference-request, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In the theory of distributions, which gives rigorous meaning to statements like $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \,dx = f(0),$$ is there also a rigorous notion of, what the physicists would call *the radial delta function*, with the property $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \delta_r(x) dx = f(0)?$$ If so, what are the properties of $\delta_r(x)$? What are the suitable test functions $f(x)$?

I would also appreciate some references for further reading.

Comment: Ok so the question is really about that (the fact that the point is at the boundary), not the expression for dirac delta in different coordinates? Then I suggest you rephrase the question to be about that. As written it's easy to get the impression you are asking about the latter.

Comment: Similar question asked before (but no answers given) [How does the Dirac delta function operate when its peak is at the boundary of an integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740355/how-does-the-dirac-delta-function-operate-when-its-peak-is-at-the-boundary-of-an) See some of the comments though.

Comment: A while a go, one of our profs defined it as follows: Consider $f_\varepsilon(x)$ Which has the values of $1/\varepsilon$ for $|x|<\varepsilon/2$ and $0$ everywhere else, $\forall \varepsilon >0$. Now in terms of $f_\varepsilon$ we define $\delta(x)=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}f_\varepsilon$. With some tricks from analysis you can derive the formula for the integral. If I remember correctly, there may have also been a way to use Cauchy's integral formula and evaluating real integrals in the complex plane to get a sensible result but I am not very familiar with that approach

Comment: What dimensionality of radial delta function are you interested in: 1, 2, or 3?  Your integral explicitly asks about the 1-dmensional version, but the reference to physicists might imply the 2-dimensionalor or 3-dimensional version.  Also, are you interested with the delta function only at the origin, or at other places in the n-dimensional space?  Bracewell's book _The Fourier Transform and Its Applications_ has a very accessible chapter 5 "The Impulse Symbol" that also gives a short treatment on 2-D and 3-D deltas and radial versions at the origin.

Comment: @AndyWalls: the radial delta function is independent of the dimensionality, because I do not care about contributions from the Jacobian. I am just looking for properties of the delta function that returns the value of the test function at the boundary.